# How could I use user_int_count to add years to the print function. Like if input the year 2000 and int count 5 it would print years 2000-2005

Tags: python, for-loop, int

```
def open_file():
    data=open("data_full.txt")
    return data


def process_file(data):
    out_file = input("Enter a name for the output file: ")
    output_file= open(out_file, "w")
    user_year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    user_int_count= int(input("Enter a integer count: "))


    cnt = 0
    data.readline()
    for line in data:
        cnt+= 1
        field = line.strip().split()

        line_list = [int(n) for n in field]

        total = sum(line_list[1:])
        year = line_list[0]
        avg = int(round((total/12),0))

        if user_year == year:
            output_file.write("{:<d}  {:<d}".format(year, avg))
            print()
            print( "{:<d}  {:<d}".format(year, avg))

    output_file.close()

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            f=open_file()
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Invalid file name. Try Again.")
    process_file(f)
    f.close()
main()
```

Comment: i think `for i to range(user_int_count): print(User_year+i)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: Your question belongs in the body of the message, not the title.

Answer (score 0):

this should print a range from the year entered through the incremented value assuming that's what your asking. If not please rephrase your question as it is a bit hard to interpret.

```
for x in range(user_year, user_year + count):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing this answer on a more literal interpretation of the question.

```
def year_range(year_date, number_of_years): #assuming these are of type int.
    output = '{}-{}'.format(year_date, year_date+number_of_years)
    print(output)
```

so year_range(2000, 5)

gives you "2000-2005"